# Unifying descriptions for all tags across SE sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

Was unable to find rationale for separate tags accros SE sites.

**Tag function**
According general definition in information systems, a [tag is a (unstructured) keyword or term assigned to a piece of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_(metadata)) (such as an Internet bookmark, digital image, database record, or computer file). This kind of metadata helps describe an item and allows it to be found again by browsing or searching. Tags are generally chosen informally and personally by the item's creator or by its viewer, depending on the system, although they may also be chosen from a controlled vocabulary.

On SE - the same: [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) is a () word or phrase that describes the topic of the question help you identify [questions that are interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics) or relevant to you.

**tag origin and quality**

Where from tags are originated and what are tag quality parametres?

**problems and contradictions examples related with SE tags**

Humanity is facing information overload. [SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) are created for collecting and sharing personal knowledge on questions or problem solving. But tag's descriptions are not matter of personal knowledge - it's just matter of [/word-meaning/](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/word-meaning/), i.e. vocabulary/dictionary, or taxonomy/ontology or, speaking in general, human lexic conceptual apparatus / framework. So why time has to be spent on fact's duplicating and sharing?

At the same time We are living at the linked data times. IMHO it's the biggest blunder having same tags with different descriptions in different SE sites unlinked. Tags (and so - descriptions) should be unified.

So I'm calling to unify all tags across SE sites as feature request. Maybe automatic linking to Wikipedia and/or some other decent dictionary would be reasonable.

**solution examples**

This is not a duplicate of [Could the tagging system be enhanced to support tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779)

Comment: `Was unable to find rationale for separate tags accros SO sites.` If you want to propose a feature, you need to provide a rational *for* implementing that feature.  It's good that you checked that there wasn't already an explanation for why it's a bad idea, but that's not *enough*.

Comment: With different SO sites you mean SO proper, SO.pt, SO.es, SO.jp and SO.ru, right?

Comment: Is this related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268885/why-dont-we-add-a-question-with-the-same-tag-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites/268892#268892 ?

Comment: How will that be helpful? There are Stack Exchange sites about programming, parenting, cooking, and music, just to name a few. How could they _possibly_ use the same tags?

Comment: @Patrick I like that you used your hammer to dupe to the question I offered but I doubt it is a correct duplicate as that question asks about bringing the questions to sites with the same tags, while this question simply asks to bring uniformity in the tags. I think my answer there would fit here but still not a duplicate IMO.

Comment: Different disciplines often use the same words but meaning different things. Linking tags just because they have the same name doesn't make any sense, and would in fact *worsen* information overload.

Comment: @rene absolute not, I'm not suggesting to link questions or tags itself across sites, just - tag lists and descriptions.

Comment: What is a tag list and its description?. Give some examples because I have no longer a clue what you want to happen.

Comment: @Won't You are talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Disambiguation ? - it's rather exception, than rule and has solutions so it's not the reason.

Comment: @rene sorry, my fault, different not SO but SE sites https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: The solution is to never do it in the first place.

Comment: Ok, here is some real data about what you describe as a blunder: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/723828. Please explain in your question how you plan to unify [tag:history] across 88 sites, or [tag:performance] on 71 sites or [tag:python] on 56 sites. Your idea only holds in theory but not on how these tags are used by each community. Nothing is broken, nothing needs fixing.

Comment: @rene thanks for real data - I'll do my best in few days.

Comment: I elaborated on @Won't's point somewhat in my answer in the linked dupe (and have just written some more verbiage, in case you feel like reading it). I do think the dupe is a good one, if only because I would want to repeat my answer almost word-for-word... which is a fairly good description of what makes a good dupe, so hey.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the idea for two reasons;

- It don't take in account that it would scrap per-site tag statistic, like top answerer.
- It don't take in account some tag, even if named the same, don't mean the same depending where it's used. Like [windows10] on superuser is related to the home usage, while the same on serverfault mean the usage in business.

Comment: I doubt that  [windows10] on superuser is related to the home usage. It's impossible to describe anything with one tag. I'd say that in general **S-A-O** (subject-action-object) system should be used for tagging. Usage patterns