# Tag Wikis: why not be unified?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

When constructing tag wikis, it seems that the tag wiki of the same tag in different websites must be built every time.

It seems that there is something can be improved. It repeats much and is not [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

For example:

The information of [tag design-patterns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/design-patterns/info) in
 softwareengineering.stackexchange.com could be the information of [the same tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/design-patterns/info) on stackoverflow.com.

I guess most tag wikis of different websites of stackexchange.com could be the same.

Because the knowledge is there, and it reflects the truth.

On the other hand, different websites of stackexchange.com has their own feature. So the community wiki may be has a content offset accordingly.

The tag wiki is unified and has its own feature on different websites of stackexchange.com.

I don't know how to achieve it.

---

I don't think this question is a duplicate of *[Unifying descriptions for all tags across SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300923/unifying-descriptions-for-all-tags-across-se-sites)*.

The question is based on the fact. I found that many tags information on other websites programming-related is to copy small part of the tag info on Stack Overflow.

Another example: [tag objective-c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/objective-c/info) on codereview.stackexchange.com is not much like the answer below at least now, compare to [the same tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/objective-c/info) on Stack Overflow.

The naming duplicate question seems that it looks good, and "I" think it is reasonable.

Talk is cheap; what I discussed exists on programming-related websites, not cooking.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cookies tag on SO is vastly different than the one on [cooking.se]

Comment: Updated, @Catija

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Tag Wiki pages are ***not*** intended to host generic content like the definitions or descriptions you might find on a Wikipedia page for that subject. The purpose of Tag Wikis is to create something unique for that site.

Tag Wikis can be used to compile a collection of resources curated by that community. It might also contain some type of organizational information only meaningful in the context that site. It may even be used to provide addtional guidance about how to use and manage the tag itself, which is often very site-specific.

If users are simply copying information from elsewhere for their tag wiki pages, that content is often flagged and removed. **There's even a specific flag reason for that.**

> *Rejected* —  This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something useful to this community specifically, and be sure to attribute the original author. See: How to reference material written by others.

Comment: To be honest the term "tag wiki" is misleading, as people believe it's like Wikipedia. But guess it's way too late to change it.

Comment: It is hard to insist the idea, that obeys the situation.  Message is meaningful to the ones who do not know it.