# Why is a tag found on one of Stack Exchange question pages rejected?

Tags: support, tags, user-interface

I just received the following error message:

> Creating the new tag 'github-for-windows' requires at least 300 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead.

This despite the fact that this tag is used on *[Where is git.exe located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928561/where-is-git-exe-located)*.
While I understand that I'm not allowed to create new tags, why can't I use one used earlier? Or how can I guess if a tag used before is no longer allowed?

Comment: This seems like a Stack Overflow specific question... but I'm curious, did you pick the tag from the tag picker or type it in from scratch? If the latter, is it possible that you had a typo?

Comment: I typed it, but I don't think there's illegal character in it...

Comment: I didn't say "illegal character"... I'm implying that you actually typed something like "gtihub-for-windows". If you pick it from the tag picker, you won't have to worry about typos.

Comment: On which site did you want to use that tag? Because on SO the [create tag privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) comes at 1500 rep. That error is not from SO and tags are per site, not across the network. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268892/158100

Comment: Well, I haven't picked it from the tag picker - I assumed, that if I copy a tag from another (quite old) question it must be defined. 
The tag was from stackoverflow and the question was posted there (see link).

Comment: So, you are saying there is absolutely no chance that you typed the wrong thing?

Comment: Absolutely no chance :-)

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. I assume you posted a question somewhere where you wanted to add the tag `[github-for-windows]`. On which site did **you** try to post your question? Was it on SuperUser.com?

Comment: Or that you have mistakenly tried to ask it on [su], where tag creation is at 300 rep (and where you also have an account)? And you did not, in fact, ask it on [so] (where tag creation is at 1,500 rep)?

Comment: Most likely you tried to ask on a different site by mistake, as @rene said. For example on Super User where you also have account, and where such tag doesn't exist, and it takes 300 rep to create new tags in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, from your description the likeliest thing is that you have tried to ask your question on Super User, which **does not** have a "github-for-windows" tag.

The error you got indicates it was on a site where tag creation privileges are gained at 300 reputation, which matches what it is set on at Super User (and doesn't match it on Stack Overflow, where the tag exists, and the privilege is set to 1,500 rep).

The two sites are *different* and have different tags (for instance, Super User has a "github-desktop" tag, which is essentially the same thing as "github-for-windows").

You have an account on both Stack Overflow and on Super User.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked and I did just that.

Comment: ._. And people were complaining the web design between SO and elsewhere was inconsistent. ;p