# Collating tag information across all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, tags

I notice that we have independent tags across multiple Stack Exchange sites on the same topic.
For example, the [go](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info) tag on Stack Overflow has the almost the same information as that on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/go/info).

IMHO, I believe that we should merge and collate information as a separate wiki platform which can be referred easily from within the Stack Exchange family of sites. This will have two-fold advantage:

1. For Users: A single go-to resource for the wiki about a specific topic.
2. For Moderators: Ease of maintenance

Would it be a good idea if I try to build a simple web application which does so?

Comment: Note that [go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/go/info) is also a board game.

Comment: Thanks for extending my point. A search page which lets you know what are the different meanings of a tag across different sites.

Comment: _"For Moderators: Ease of maintenence"_ Care to explain how? As the tags are, theoretically, used and moderated differently on different sites with different scopes, how would this page make it easier for moderators to maintain tags? For example, how would maintaining that go tag be easier for Stack Overflow mods, or Software Engineering mods?

Comment: _"Would it be a good idea if I try to build a simple web application which does so?"_ I feel like this isn't a good question for our site- It's not about the site itself, it's about a project you want to work on. If you want to, rather, ask if this page would be useful... That might be a better, more on topic question as it's about the site and a potential feature that could be added to the site at some point.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268885/why-dont-we-add-a-question-with-the-same-tag-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites/268892#268892

Answer (score 4):

To my mind there are two key drawbacks in attempting to collate cross-site tag information:

1. You'd need cross-site privileges to maintain the tags. That creates issues centred around how much reputation would you have to attain to be a credible tag maintainer. And across which sites ought this reputation be earned? Inevitably, Stack Exchange employees would become burdened with the cross-site tag maintenance; and commercial constraints would be at odds with that.
2. Tags with similar names can mean very different things depending on sites; would a consensus ever be reached? For example C is a programming language on Stack Overflow, but is also the root note (middle C) in Western Music. Go is a programming language, but it is a popular board game especially in Asian cultures.

The Stack Exchange sites are unified insofar that the underlying engine is unified. But they are intentionally disparate sites; as well as the questions, that includes the tags.