# Could the path /questions/tagged/TAGS be added networkwide, too?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, stackexchange.com

On any site, we can use `/questions/tagged/TAGS` - this is the URL you'll get after clicking on a tag. For example, the questions tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) on [this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) or on [some per-site-meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion). And a similar link is result of a search using only tags - when you [enter [discussion] [hyperlinks]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiscussion%5D+%5Bhyperlinks%5D), you are automatically redirected to [/tagged/discussion+hyperlinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion+hyperlinks).

I think that sometimes people might be interested in seeing questions from some tag(s) on several sites.

However, if instead of the original address I start with `stackexchange.com` I get a link that doesn't work: https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion. Could something like this be added? (I can still find questions with the given tag by [searching for [discussion] is:q](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiscussion%5D+is%3Aq). And I can create [a filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-filters/info) to see the recent questions in some given tag. Still, this would add one additional way how to get such questions. And filters have the advantage that I can choose [only meta sites](https://stackexchange.com/filters/440220/discussion-metas) or only some specific sites.)

---

A random example - you can replace this by any other topic. Recently I have seen a question about a bug in MathJax, in the question it was mentioned that it was on Safari.
So I decided to check whether there were similar bug report in the past.

If I [search on a per-site-meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+%5Bmathjax%5D+safari) for the word safari among posts tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax), then I can simply remove the site-specific part and leave just `stackexchange.com` and I get [a link that works](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+%5Bmathjax%5D+safari)

However, if I [put only tags into a search](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+mathjax+safari) the URL that I get has the format `/questions/tagged/TAGS`. And now removing the site-specific part [leaves a link which doesn't work](https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+mathjax+safari).

As mentioned above, I can still search for such questions [in a different way](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+%5Bmathjax%5D+%5Bsafari%5D+is:q).

---

To include something which would be more difficult to do currently -- on a page with tags there is a frequent tab. It can be approximated with a SEDE query ([all sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1676609/most-frequently-linked-questions-in-the-given-tag-networkwide-all-sites?tagname=mathjax) and [specifically metas](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1676605/most-frequently-linked-questions-in-the-given-tag-networkwide-only-metas?tagname=mathjax)) - but it's not really that straightforward. (At the same time, I won't be surprised if including tabs would be more difficult than a straightforward search.)

---

Based on the comments, it seems that other people tend to work differently, I will just mention that I was many times in the situation when like this: "I see a bug report on our local meta. But I guess this bug must have been noticed by somebody else before. Let me search first for posts tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [topic](/questions/tagged/topic) on the per-site-meta. And then maybe the same search either on Meta Stack Exchange or networkwide - after all, tags on per-site-metas often have rather similar names." To do this, quite quick way is to simply change `math.meta.stackexchange.com` to `meta.stackexchange.com` or to `stackexchange.com` in the address bar - I'll get basically the same search. (Of course, with some limitations in the case of the networkwide search.)

So in this way I sometimes arrived to the links described above.

---

I understand that this is something very minor and rather low priority. (So I guess it is worth looking into only if this is straightforward to implement. If the developers have some time that can be devoted to networkwide search, the [known problems with pagination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359216) are definitely something much more important than this.) Still, I thought that I'd put this suggestion here - at least to see what others think about that.

Comment: You think that apple in cooking would have anything to do with apple in computing? Or safari in travel vs computing safari?

Comment: One of the features of the /questions/tagged/TAG routes on sites is that the "Active" and "Newest" tabs get live updates through the SE WebSocket. Are you proposing that these newly created routes should also get live updates from every site on the network?

Comment: @Makyen Certainly I wouldn't be opposed to having tabs here, too. (Be it with the live updates or without them.) Although it is possible that there might be some technical complications with that - probably somebody who know more about the SE software would have to say whether this would lead to something too computationally expensive. (Another thing which I realized only later - thanks to the comment about apple(s) - is that for a single site it is clear how synonyms should be treated. I suppose that using synonyms networkwide might become messy and perhaps on resources.)

Comment: You basically say that you can accomplish the thing you really want, which is to see a list of questions with a tag or tags across the entire SE Network, using the all-SE search. You can also do so by setting up a question filter on the SE site, which could also be used to email you a digest of such questions at various intervals. It's not clear to me from what you've said in the question what the benefit is, other than purely URL semantic, from having the routes you're asking for. What is really gained from having these additional routes, other than letting people manually create those URLs?

Comment: @Makyen If nothing else, the things would be at least a bit more consistent. As the things currently work, in some cases you can go from site-specific search to networkwide search by editing the URL, in some cases you can't. And, of course, if the SE would decide to implement this in a way which would include tabs, there certainly are things which can be done neither through search nor with filters. But as I said before, I am not in the position to judge whether this would be feasible. And I have explicitly mentioned that I do consider this a rather minor thing.

Comment: Of course I am perfectly fine with a response saying that this would be useless for most users - maybe the fact that I ran into this quite often simply means that I use SE in a non-standard way, compared to other people.

Comment: I wonder if this is something that could be mocked up from RSS feeds and some tool to combine them...

Comment: `... started with stackexchange.com I get a link that doesn't work: https://stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion. Could something like this be added?` --- Try this URL: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiscussion%5D

Comment: I have answered a somewhat related question a while ago, about cross site tagging: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268885/why-dont-we-add-a-question-with-the-same-tag-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites/268892#268892

Comment: I am a bit torn whether I should simply delete this question - since several users say in comments that this suggestion is very unlikely to be useful. At the same time, the feedback given in the comments contains some information that could be possibly useful - so maybe it is still worth preserving that.